# c++ - Custom memory manager abstraction

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, abstraction

The project I'm working on needs custom memory management, since it uses does a lot of allocations and deallocations. I need to implement stack-like memories and some custom heap-like memories, which work fast with my application. Also, I need the STL containers to use these custom allocators, whenever possible.

Right now, I'm unfamiliar with the best practices of implementing a custom memory manager and I have other priorities to look forward to.

So, given the above requirements, I'm looking for an elegant way of abstracting the memory management internals, so that it can just use `new` and `delete` for now, and when required, can be changed to the custom allocators without much headache?

Pardon me for any wrong terminology use!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard interface for custom memory allocators in C++ is [Allocator concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator).

The default implementation, [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator), uses `new` and `delete`, but you can provide your own later and if you conform to the interface, you can use it with standard collections.

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna use this for now, just hoping I don't end up shooting myself in the foot because of the increased complexity! Also, I can use these allocators to allocate memory separately from the STL containers, right?

Comment: @Bruce: The complexity is there to support placement new that the vector needs. You can probably find existing implementations that may suit your needs like [Boost.Pool](http://www.boost.org/libs/pool/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: @Bruce: Of course you can allocate from allocator manually. You might want to write a simple wrapper so you don't have to call the `allocate`/`construct` and `destroy`/`deallocate` pairs manually each time.

Comment: I'm getting a bit confused here. `std::allocator`, or allocators in general, are class templates, right? So do I have to create an instance of that allocator in order to use it? Suppose I have many different datatypes. Then do I have to instantiate an allocator with the template argument for each of them?

Comment: @Bruce: Well, for the collections yes. And many collections actually `rebind` it, because they don't allocate their value type, but instead some internal type that includes it. So the allocators should better be lightweight and share pointer to the actual pool.

Comment: @Bruce: Note, that memory pools are only worth the trouble if you are allocating large number of objects of the same size. If you have many types, you probably don't have many instances of _each_ and the standard allocator is probably fine for most of them.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function or class the provide this two function like `Pool::New() and Pool::Delete()` and implement with the raw `new and delete`, and really design it when you are ready.

Some simple template technique may required. Just template-lized the (member)function.

Comment: But there's no way to tell the STL containers to use this pool.